# Flutter: Get.back() function triggers ZoomDrawer

Tags: flutter

I have a very simple Appbar with Get.back()function and ZoomDrawer. and ZoomDrawer is being opened every time i tap back button. and i have know idea why.. could this be bug of either plugins?

```
AppBar(
      elevation: 0.0,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () => Get.back()
        ,
      ),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.black, //change your color here
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
```

```
class SomeScreen extends GetView<MyDrawerController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.put<MyDrawerController>(MyDrawerController());
    return GetBuilder<MyDrawerController>(
        builder: (_) => ZoomDrawer(
          controller: _.zoomDrawerController,
          menuScreen: Drawer(),
          mainScreen: AnotherScreen(),
          borderRadius: 24.0,
          showShadow: true,
          angle: -12.0,
          drawerShadowsBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          slideWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your screen by [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html). Inside `onWillPop` add the code that open your drawer. This widget will call `onWillPop` everytime you pop a screen, return a bool in onWillPop that allow pop action continue or not.

Comment: onWillPop is already implemented. this is so strange because it happens on other drawer plugins too(flutter_slider_drawer). so it must be something to do with Getx plugin. i stepped to every execution of Get.back() but i had nothing except screen shows with drawer wide open on handleDrawFrame() executing.